# calculate the exact number of minutes for employee based on his schedule

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains the employees Punch time

https://www.webdigitronix.com/emo.JPG

```
id          tktno   flag    timing                      empid
1117464     1       OFFICE  2019-08-17 08:40:21.000     1
1117465     1       OFFICE  2019-08-17 09:40:21.000     1
1117466     1       OFFICE  2019-08-17 09:50:21.000     1
1117467     1       OFFICE  2019-08-17 11:50:21.000     1
```

First   Row Intime - "08:40:21.000"
Second Row Outtime- "09:40:21.000"

on same day emp punch again

Third  Row Intime - "09:50:21.000"
Fourth Row Outtime- "11:50:21.000"

I want to calculate how much time  (min) spend by emp in office

Comment: Data saved in database as you shown?

Comment: Duplicate on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00c13aae-5d55-40a1-8156-a8ed101fb44a/calculate-how-much-time-min-spend-by-emp-in-office?forum=transactsql). It is wasteful to post the same question independently to multiple forums. At least link them so others don't waste efforts asking the same questions and providing the same queries.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). Especially if they are hosted somewhere likely to disappear. So, what have you tried?

Comment: Which of these rows are punch in and which punch out? How can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is based on MS SQL DB, try following for your desired result:

```
select EmpID, flag,
       DATEDIFF (MINUTE,
                MIN (Timing),
                MAX (Timing)
               ) as DurationMinutes
from EmpTable
Group by EmpID, flag
```